# Data model for SCORM in Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design

I would like to partially implement SCORM standard in my Rails app.

My current data model has the following structure. I have `users`, I have `courses`, I have join table `user_courses` (each row is data for the course started by some user). The latter table has all attributes (columns) that SCORM requires to implement (max score, min score, raw score etc.)

Everything is plain and easy until I get to objectives. It says that SCORM-compliant LMS should support at least 100 objectives. If it were only 4 or 5, I would create 4 or 5 more columns in my `user_courses` table, but it doesn't have any sense to create 100 as user will probably use 5 to 10.

What is the best way to handle such problem?

Answer (score 1):

How do objectives relate to the current tables?

**EDIT**:

I'm assuming a course will have a pre-set Objectives and they won't need to track these objectives seperatly per user.

Create table: objectives with objective_id
Create table: course_objectives with course_id, objective_id

You can link course to course_objectives (a course has many objectives) and link objectives to course (an objective can belong to many courses). This will allow you to re-use common objectives between courses. If this is not the case, then you can skip course_objectives and just use objectives to course as, a course can have many objectives.

Does this help?

If you do need to track the progress or status of objectives per user, you'll need another table between user_courses and course_objectives.

-Dan

Comment: Every user in every course has multiple objectives.